# Ajax post request data limit in sinatra

Tags: jquery, ajax, sinatra

I have to submit large data in sinatra using ajax call. I am using post request for that. However, I can send 1081 characters send successfully. After that, I am getting internal server error. I have checked solutions on the web, they are saying to set up maxallowedcontent. However, I am not sure where to set in sinatra that.

Here's my ajax code

```
predata= ($($('pre')[0]).text()).slice(0,1081);
  a = {"A":predata};
  data = JSON.stringify(a);
  // data = JSON.stringify({"a":"a"});
  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url:''+self.location+'form_save'  ,
    dataType: "json" ,
    error: function (error) {
           console.log(error);
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log("success");
    }
  });
```

worked successfully for slicing 1081 characters but more than 1081 characters it's giving internal server error. Please help me, I got stuck from 4 hours over here.

Comment: Have you solved this? Is there any stack trace or error message? Which server are you using: Thin, Puma, Webrick?